# Can't make JQuery UI Sortable work properly by Changing places with the Element

Tags: html, jquery-ui, bootstrap-grid

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
      connectWith: ".sortable"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='row sortable'>
    <a class='btn btn-primary col-6'>A</a>
    <a class='btn btn-primary col-6'>B</a>
    <a class='btn btn-primary col-6'>C</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the button replace places with each other, So if i pulled `button C` up to `button A` i expect it to swap each other place, But instead what happens is that `button C` enters the place of `button A` and push all buttons back, But I just want them to replace each other places and not reorder each other places.

usual look:

```
A B
C
```

What I want to happen When I pull `C` to the place of `A`:

```
C B
A
```

What actually happens:

```
C A
B
```

How can I make it replaced instead of pushed?

Comment: The activity that you described is the default function of Sortable. You might be able to pull it off with Sortable and I think Draggable and Droppable would be a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, it might be better to use Draggable and Droppable to perform a swap function. Sortable is designed to allow you to change the order or the item in your list to any other position in the list.

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".row .droparea").droppable({
    accept: ".btn",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "active"
    },
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      var si = ui.draggable.data("start");
      $(".btn", this)
        .detach()
        .appendTo($(".droparea").eq(si));
      ui.draggable.css({
        top: "",
        left: ""
      }).appendTo($(this));
    }
  });

  $(".row .btn").each(function(i, el) {
    $("<i>", {
      class: "fas fa-arrows-alt fa-fw drag-handle",
      style: "display: inline-block; width: 17px; height: 100%; margin-left: -17px;",
      title: "Click to Drag"
    }).appendTo($(el)).position({
      my: "right center",
      at: "right-3 center",
      of: $(el)
    });
    $(el).draggable({
      containment: ".row",
      handle: ".drag-handle",
      opacity: 0.45,
      zIndex: 1000,
      start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.helper.data("start", $(this).parent().index());
      }
    }).disableSelection();
  });
});
```

```css
.row .btn {
  width: 100%;
}

.row .btn .drag-handle {
  color: #0094ff;
}

.row .active .btn {
  border: 1px dashed #212529;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="droparea col-6">
      <a class='btn btn-primary'>A</a>
    </div>
    <div class="droparea col-6">
      <a class='btn btn-primary'>B</a>
    </div>
    <div class="droparea col-6">
      <a class='btn btn-primary'>C</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the `.droparea` wrappers, we can make spots for a `.btn` to be dragged onto. When we drop the `.btn`, it then swaps the two.

For example, if we drag `C` to the `A` position, `A` is detached and re-attached to position that `C` was at. `C` is then attached in place of `A`.

Giving the user some more feedback, so they know when a button can be dropped is somewhat important. I added some of that and also used Font Awesome to create the handle icons. The handle icons are sort of import if you plan to maintain the buttons `click` functionality. `click` shouldn't bubble over `mousedown`, but this is just making it less ambiguous and also more clear to the user.